# Why is getFeeForMessage intermittently returning a null value?

Tags: fees

We have an issue where `getFeeForMessage` intermittently returns `null` for the `value` property. The `context` property is returned correctly. We are using web3.js and the logic there and in the rust code doesn't look like it should ever return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you were sending transactions with an invalid recent block hash (meaning the "recentBlockhash" you used is too old). This could happen if the time in between constructing the transaction and sending to `getFeeForMessage` was too long.